# How to change an application's exe.config file when it is being installed using Windows Installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, installation

I have created a Windows Service application.

I have also created a Windows Installer for the Service Application.

On the installer project, I have added a custom screen that presents users with a screen to enter values (right click setup project -> View -> User Interface -> Right click the 'Start' section -> Add dialog -> Text boxes -> OK)

I have added the property as an argument to the custom action.

I have added code to:

```
private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
```

and was able to write the custom value entered using the installation process to a text file.

```
private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"c:\test\123.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path).Dispose();
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            tw.WriteLine("The setting is: " + Context.Parameters["PathValue"]);
            tw.Close();
        }

    }

    else if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            tw.WriteLine("The setting is: " + Context.Parameters["PathValue"]);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Now, I only want to write the value into the application's applicationame.exe.config file.**

I have created a config file for the service using the Project Properties window: [image]

Note: After the screenshot was taken, I also tried changing the `Access Modifier` on the top right of the screen from `Internal` to `Public` and still the same result.

The applicationname.exe.config file generated is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsService2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <WindowsService2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="setting1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>default111</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsService2.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

**How can I write to this without manually parsing the XML?**

Note that my applicationname.exe.config file is **not** in the format: `<add key="setting1" value="default111" />` for some reason.

Also, I don't have a app.config file in the bin folder. I only have applicationname.exe.config.

[image]

I've tried this. But this doesn't update the application.exe.config file nor does it throw any errors.

```
private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{

    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting1"];
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting1"] = Context.Parameters["PathValue"];
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

}
```

I've also tried the following and it didn't work (no error messages though):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("setting1", Context.Parameters["PathValue"]);
```

Please be kind enough to help me figure out how I can write the value to the applicationame.exe.config file without parsing the XML file.

Comment: What are you placing in your config file that you need to change at install time?

Comment: The service monitors a specific folder and processes files in it. I want the users to be able to set that during the installation process

Answer (score 1):

The overall issue is that you are not running in an application environment. Your code is being called from msiexec.exe via reflection of your installed assembly, and probably running under the SYSTEM account. That's why it doesn't just work.

Another possible issue is that your Bin folder screenshot is irrelevant. There is no connection between the Bin folder and the installed locations of your files (which most likely is in Program Files), and there is no evidence that you included your config file in your install. There is no rule "everything in the Bin folder gets installed to the system". So a screen shot of your destination Application folder would be more useful to see if the config file is there - your custom action will run after all the files are installed, so take a look there.

It's also not clear (at least to me) that GetExecutionAssembly().Location will return the correct value. The assembly is loaded and instantiated using reflection when managed code custom actions are called, and the docs for location imply that a LoadByte assembly (which might be used in the loading code) results in empty string.  Therefore it might be worth trying a different method, such as GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.

Also, adding paths as arguments to installer classes needs to be done very carefully, and your post doesn't show what you did. If your property name is MYPATH (and it must be uppercase) then your argument needs to be  /PathValue="[MYPROP]\" with that trailing backslash. There are a bunch of parameters passed into the installer class methods (including your assembly name) and the backslash is there to stop the entire parameter list becoming incoherent. You won't get this issue in your other custom action because yours is the only parameter being passed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` *does* return the correct location where the application is being installed (i have this written to a random text file and it checked out). And also, that is the exact way that I added the argument to the installer. I didn't go into detail on that since accepting the argument from the user works fine as mentioned (again, as mentioend, i've written the argument to a random text file and it checks out). The issue is when writing it to the application's <assemblyname>.exe.config file

Comment: The potential issue was that passing it incorrectly would result in your text file working but the installer class wouldn't work because it's mangled in with a bunch of other parameters because the hidden parser in the the installer class interface is trying to collect 5 or 6 parameters all /something=onething etc. Anyway, hopefully you're making progress.

Answer (score 0):

The [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class is definitely  what you are looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConfigModifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string fileName = @"C:\Some\entered\path\appName.exe.config";
            xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
            xmlDoc["configuration"]["applicationSettings"]["WindowsService2.Properties.Settings"]["setting"]["value"].InnerText = "My New Value";
            xmlDoc.Save(fileName);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Since this is a config file that was created automatically, i was actually, looking for something such as the `ConfigurationManager` class that would allow updates to the exe.config file directly (without using XML classes)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like wasting time on reinventing the wheel you can find tools like Advanced Installer (*disclaimer: I work on the team building it*) that will do this for you, without writing any code.

Here is a [video that show the XML updater from Advanced Installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOpcHyzIrr4).

Also more docs on this:

[XML updater documentation](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/edit-xml-file-dialog.html)

[XML updater example for web.config file](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-import-edit-xml-file.html)

Probably the are other tools similar to Advanced Installer that can do this, but all paid tools. It is just a question of how much is your time worth.